# How to manage contacts with associated org notes (to build a light CRM)?

Tags: org-mode, org-contacts

I started using Org-Mode 10 years ago to implement a [GTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done) like system, which introduced me to Emacs. Being so gratified and continually finding new usages, I now use Org-Mode for almost everything.

This time I'd like to use Emacs/Org-Mode as a light [CRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management), which would consist of:

- Being able to manage contacts
- Being able for each contact to take substantial notes using Org-Mode functionalities (headlines, markups, links, etc.)
- Being able to create tasks in org-agenda that would refer to/be linked with the contacts

Searching for such a solution I found some contact management tools such as EBDB, org-contacts, or Hyrolo, but reading their documentation didn't help me know if they were suited for my use case.

Would you have any idea of how to implement such a light CRM (my emacs-elisp knowledge is close to zero)?

Comment: How many contacts would you like to manage? Because if they are only a few hundreds then I would suggest you start using `org-contacts` immediately, as it is a no-brainer and you can easily switch at anytime. You can make the birthdays show up in the agenda (I'm sure because it works here). As the contacts are just org-headings, I assume you can easily link to them and I expect that you can add custom text under the headline (or use a :NOTES: property). EBDB and BBDB are powertools, that would probably fulfill all your needs too, but they take much longer to configure. Hyrolo I don't know.

Comment: The following link could be helpful https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/8toivy/tip_how_to_manage_your_contacts_with_orgcontacts/

Comment: Thanks for you help. My main concern with `org-contacts` is it that seems that it's no longer maintained (I'd be afraid to invest time in a tool that'd be decommissioned). As for the number of contacts it would be tens at first, but the goal  would be to have 1 or 2 thousands (I'd also like to manage my google contacts with it). Do you know if `org-contacts` has the ability to import/export other formats (google-contacts, vcards, csv, etc.)? Can I use org features (headlines, markups, links, etc.) within :NOTES fields ? If yes these fields would contain lots of texts (like minutes from calls).

Comment: You might find [Bernt Hansen's writeup of how he uses Org mode to handle phone calls](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#HandlinePhoneCalls) interesting. The whole document is worth reading (but take it in small chunks or you'll get indigestion). He uses BBDB by the way.

Comment: Thanks @NIckD, I'll give EBDB a try then. If I manage to set up a satisfying implementation, I'll post the details here as an answer to my question.

Comment: @crocefisso With org-contacts it is easy to import and export using [org-vcard](https://github.com/flexibeast/org-vcard/tree/f4b7445550deb30e170a25fc42541e99730e21d0). I don't know about the notes fields, but it is easy to check because you can setup org-contacts in seconds. However, if you plan to manage huge amounts (say > 1000) of contacts, then I would say it is probably worth it to invest time to learn/configure BBDB/EBDB...